# Getting ArcPy Error 00354

Tags: arcpy, error-000210, error-000354

Just to get the obvious out of the way, I am very new to python and arcpy. I know almost nothing. That being said, I've inherited a script that is run once a year and I'm now the only one responsible for running (and fixing) it. I actually ran the script last year with no problems.

The relevant bit of code is as follows:

```
import os
import sys
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import shutil
import subprocess


# Folder location will need to be changed every year
# There are two instances of the year in the script. Use the search function to find them.
basFolder = '\\\\havc.local\\misc\\GIS\\Regional\\Boundary and Annexation Survey (BAS)\\2020 BAS\\'


print "If the city is two words, do not add a space.\n"


# user to input the city name for the script
userInput = raw_input('Enter city:\n')
inputFolder = os.path.join(basFolder, userInput)
basReturnDirectory = os.path.join(basFolder, userInput + '\\BASReturn')


# check if folder exists
if os.path.exists(inputFolder):

    print "\n"
    # print out the input folder as specified by the user
    print "Input Folder: " + inputFolder

    # create BASReturn folder for final deliverables
    if not os.path.exists(basReturnDirectory):
        os.makedirs(basReturnDirectory)

    # set the environment to list the mxds
    arcpy.env.workspace = inputFolder

    for file in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):

        mxd_path = os.path.join(inputFolder, file)
        print "MXD Path: " + mxd_path

        # reset the environment to the database
        env.workspace = inputFolder + '\\' + userInput + '_2020.gdb'
        print "env.workspace: " + env.workspace
        # map variables
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_path)
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
        havcData = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "HavcData", df)
        censusData = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "CensusData", df)
        unionFC = "union"
        union_m2s = "union_multisingle"

        # create the change polygons
        print "Creating the change polygons..."

        arcpy.Union_analysis([censusData, havcData], unionFC)

        # delete the shared feature
        print "Deleting shared feature..."

        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(unionFC, "OBJECTID") as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                if row[0]>2:
                    cursor.deleteRow()
```

Powershell returns the following:

```
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\havc.local\misc\GIS\Regional\Boundary and Annexation Survey (BAS)\2020 BAS> python BASupdate.py
If the city is two words, do not add a space.

Enter city:
Aiken


Input Folder: \\havc.local\misc\GIS\Regional\Boundary and Annexation Survey (BAS)\2020 BAS\Aiken
MXD Path: \\havc.local\misc\GIS\Regional\Boundary and Annexation Survey (BAS)\2020 BAS\Aiken\AikenBAS.mxd
env.workspace: \\havc.local\misc\GIS\Regional\Boundary and Annexation Survey (BAS)\2020 BAS\Aiken\Aiken_2020.gdb
Creating the change polygons...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BASupdate.py", line 56, in <module>
    arcpy.Union_analysis([censusData, havcData], unionFC)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 628, in Union
    raise e
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output \\havc.local\misc\GIS\Regional\Boundary and Annexation Survey (BAS)\2020 BAS\Aiken\Aiken_2020.gdb\union.shp.shp
ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
Failed to execute (Union).

PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\havc.local\misc\GIS\Regional\Boundary and Annexation Survey (BAS)\2020 BAS>
```

As you can see in the error message, it looks like the script is trying to put shapefiles inside of a geodatabase. I have no idea why. The environment is set to use a geodatabase that is determined by a combination of the userInput and the file directory for the project. This worked flawlessly last year. If there is any more information that I can provide, please let me know.

**EDIT**: I have actually come to believe that it is not a python issue. The script is run on two different polygons and looks for change. I decided to try it out on another set of polygons, and it worked flawlessly. This has led me to believe that it could potentially be a geometry issue. The initial polygons (that failed) are not exactly simple. 
[image: Polygon]

I ran the bad geometry data checks using data reviewer and the geometry repair tools, however, and nothing was returned. I'm honestly at a loss here.

**Edit 2:** So as others have pointed out, this does seem to be an issue with the workspace. I replaced this line

```
env.workspace = inputFolder + '\\' + userInput + '_2020.gdb'
```

with this

```
env.workspace = '\\\\havc.local\\misc\\GIS\\Regional\\Boundary and Annexation Survey (BAS)\\2020 BAS\\Aiken\\Test.gdb'
```

and it ran just fine. The Test.gdb was a newly created empty file geodatabase. What I can't figure out is why this particular user input is the only one that has this problem. You can type anything else as the input, and as long as you have a file geodatabase in place named following the script schema, it will run.

Comment: In this case, I am the user! I didn't add .shp nor is it called for anywhere in the script. It's driving me crazy!

Comment: Numerous potential solutions: Per the [ArcGIS help](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-00351-00375-000354.htm), have you tried checking all the fc names and field names of fc for potential invalid characters (even one wrong character would cause error)?  Does the file gdb "Aiken_2020.gdb" exist or any locks on the geodatabase (see arcgis help for [error 00210](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012542))?

Comment: @jbrengel Thanks for the response! I have checked these things. The field names don't have any special characters aside from an occasional number or underscore. I'm working with census data, so it is their typical format. The file gdb does exist and doesn't have any locks either. What makes it even stranger is the fact that changing nothing other than the polygons used, the tool runs flawlessly. They have the same fields and the same geodatabase!

Comment: @Matt Beal.  yw.  do the polygons that work add a ".shp" to the output feature class of the union tool?  for just these "bad polygons", have you tried hard coding in the files to the input feature classes and output feature feature class inside of the union tool? i'd even go step by step in your script using just these troublesome polygons (not using a for loop).

Comment: to me, a bad geometry still doesn't directly explain why, for these particular polygons, it's generating those particular errors (which are caused by invalid characters/naming or something to do in the file structure- in this case, seemingly the **".shp.shp"** at end of union).

Comment: It looks like arcpy is not understanding that env.workspace is an existing gdb. Try: `arcpy.Exists(env.workspace)`, should return `true`

Comment: @jbrengel You are correct. It doesn't appear that geometry is the issue. The issue is with the workspace environment. I replaced this line 

        env.workspace = inputFolder + '\\' + userInput + '_2020.gdb'

with this

env.workspace = "\\\\havc.local\\misc\\GIS\\Regional\\Boundary and Annexation Survey (BAS)\\2020 BAS\\Aiken\\Test.gdb"

and it ran perfectly. 

What I cannot understand is that this script works fine when using any other city as an input and has even worked with this city in the past. I am genuinely stumped.

Comment: @BERA You are correct. It was not recognizing that workspace for some reason, but I can't figure out why. I hardcoded a test geodatabase, which was just a new empty one in place of the current workspace, and it ran flawlessly. I just can't figure out why this particular input city is returning this error and no others. It has even worked before with this city.

Comment: Ok. What does `print env.workspace` print out for that city?

Comment: I Think some of the charachters for certain cities are interpreted as escape charachters see for example [this tutorial](https://www.pitt.edu/~naraehan/python2/tutorial7.html). Try adding a r for raw in front of all paths, for example `r'C:\data.gdb'`

Comment: @BERA Hmmm. So that is interesting. When adding print env.workspace into the code, it actually give the correct path to the geodatabase, but twice. Here is what that portion of the code returned 

"\\havc.local\misc\GIS\Regional\Boundary and Annexation Survey (BAS)\2020 BAS\Aiken\Aiken_2020.gdb
\\havc.local\misc\GIS\Regional\Boundary and Annexation Survey (BAS)\2020 BAS\Aiken\Aiken_2020.gdb

Comment: In addition to @BERA's comment, try using the `os` module and string formatting, rather than string concatenation, to build your paths. e.g. `os.path.join(inputFolder, "{}_2020".format(userIntput))`.  Also refer to this thread which talks about workarounds for issues with paths that have spaces: https://community.esri.com/thread/228534-how-can-i-work-around-path-names-in-arcpy-having-spaces-in-them-if-i-can